# Allowing folder creation at sub-folder level

Tags: document-library, permissions

I want to deny users the ability to create folders at the top level. But in folder level 3, users should be able to create folder to manage documents. Any advice on how to do this?

```
Level 1 - No new folders
-> Level 2 - No new folders
-> -> Level 3 - Ability to create new folders
```

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** For Level 1
- Open Library in the ribbon at top under **Library** option . There is **Share With**  as shown in below image
[image: Level 1]
Share With --> Advanced --> Stop inheriting.
Here you will manage level 1 permission
Stop inheriting permission and give **read** access.

**Step 2:** For Level 2
- Click **...** next to folder at level 2 and again **...** like below image
- There you will find **Share With** from there its same as level 1. There you will manage Level 2 permission.
[image: Level 2] 
Stop inheriting permission and give **read** access.

**Step 3 :** For Level 3
- Follow same steps for sub folder level , like level 2. 
Stop inheriting permission and give **Contribute** access.

Comment: Any advice on how to manage those access levels. I tried following other steps, and was unable to accomplish what I was looking for. I am only finding persmission controls for Level 1, not 2 or 3

Comment: Modified my answer. Hope it helps .